# Print Record fields in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I print all the fields of a record variable in PL/SQL.
The record variable has got lots of fields so is there a better way than printing each field?
Also tried dynamic sql but didn't help.

Comment: Are you trying to print out the database field names, or the values?

Comment: I am trying to print the Field Name and its corresponding value.

Comment: I think what you want is to use a [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/06_ora.htm#i36655). I am with DOK... you want to print all the fields in one record without printing each field?  A more precise wording of the question might help.

Comment: Suppose there is a table with 50 columns (col1, col2...col50) and I have a record variable which is based on that table. I would want to print out all the 50 values in that record variable. Sample output: 
Col1 : Val1
Col2 : Val2
.
.
Col3 : Val50

Answer (score 9):

Building on Ollies use of dbms_output, but for to dynamically go through the cursor

set up for test

```
/*create table temp (aa varchar2(50) , bb number , cc date ) ;

insert into temp (aa,bb,cc)
  select chr(level+100) , level, sysdate+level
    from dual
     connect by level < 15 ;
/
*/
```

---

Block to show the test (this assumes 11g)

```
set serveroutput on
declare
   l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR ;

    PROCEDURE CursorOutput(
                            p_refcursor        IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                         )  
    AS
        l_desc          DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB ;
        l_cols          BINARY_INTEGER ;
        l_cursor        BINARY_INTEGER ;
        v_varchar2      VARCHAR2( 4000 ) ;
        v_number        NUMBER ;
        v_date          DATE ;
        l_data          varchar2( 32767 ) ;
        l_columnValue   VARCHAR2( 32767 ) ;
        l_processedRows Number := 0;
    BEGIN

        /* Convert refcursor "parameter" to DBMS_SQL cursor... */
        l_cursor := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER( p_refcursor );
        /* Describe the cursor... */
        DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS( l_cursor, l_cols, l_desc );

        /* Define columns to be fetched. We're only using V2, NUM, DATE for example...
        for a complete list of the col_types this link is accessible.
        http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm#45504
        http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=912475
        if not a usable type, will throw new exception
        */
         FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols LOOP
             IF l_desc(i).col_type = 2 THEN
               DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor, i, v_number);
            ELSIF l_desc(i).col_type = 12 THEN
               DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor, i, v_date);
            ELSif l_desc(i).col_type = 01 or l_desc(i).col_type = 96 then
               DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor, i, v_varchar2, 4000);
            else
                --raise an exception if the user's query contains a datatype not (yet) supported by this procedure
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid Data Type for conversion to delimited file. {' || l_desc(i).col_name || '}');
            END IF;
          END LOOP;


        /* -- print out the column names if desired
             FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols LOOP
                     dbms_output.put_line('** ' || l_desc(i).col_name) ;
             END LOOP;
        */

         /* Fetch all data... */
         WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(l_cursor) > 0 LOOP
             dbms_output.put_line('LINE: '  || l_processedRows || '');
             FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols LOOP
                 if l_desc(i).col_type = 12 THEN --we are in a date
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor, i, v_date);
                    v_varchar2 := to_char(v_date , 'dd-MON-yyyy' ) ;
                 elsif  l_desc(i).col_type = 2 THEN --we are in a number
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor, i, v_number);
                    v_varchar2 := to_char(v_number) ;
                 else --treat it as a string (should be varchar2,char,etc)
                    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor, i, v_varchar2);
                    IF v_varchar2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                       v_varchar2 := '"' || v_varchar2 || '"' ;
                       ELSE
                       v_varchar2 := '';
                    END IF ;
                 end if ;
                 dbms_output.put_line(l_desc(i).col_name || '=>' || v_varchar2) ;
             END LOOP;
             l_processedRows := l_processedRows + 1 ;
          END LOOP;

          dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);
          dbms_output.put_line('I found and processed  '  || l_processedRows || ' rows .');

    END;

begin
        open l_cur for select * from temp;

        CursorOutput(p_refcursor => l_cur) ;

end ;
/
```

---

will give you this result

```
LINE: 0
AA=>"e"
BB=>1
CC=>04-JAN-2012
LINE: 1
AA=>"f"
BB=>2
CC=>05-JAN-2012
LINE: 2
AA=>"g"
BB=>3
CC=>06-JAN-2012
LINE: 3
AA=>"h"
BB=>4
CC=>07-JAN-2012
LINE: 4
AA=>"i"
BB=>5
CC=>08-JAN-2012
LINE: 5
AA=>"j"
BB=>6
CC=>09-JAN-2012
LINE: 6
AA=>"k"
BB=>7
CC=>10-JAN-2012
LINE: 7
AA=>"l"
BB=>8
CC=>11-JAN-2012
LINE: 8
AA=>"m"
BB=>9
CC=>12-JAN-2012
LINE: 9
AA=>"n"
BB=>10
CC=>13-JAN-2012
LINE: 10
AA=>"o"
BB=>11
CC=>14-JAN-2012
LINE: 11
AA=>"p"
BB=>12
CC=>15-JAN-2012
LINE: 12
AA=>"q"
BB=>13
CC=>16-JAN-2012
LINE: 13
AA=>"r"
BB=>14
CC=>17-JAN-2012
I found and processed  14 rows .
```

I had done something similar to this to dynamically build a csv file utilizing these two links as sources
    http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=505
    http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059

Depending on what you are going for, however, you may just want to run it in SQL Developer (or Toad) and export the results!

Comment: This really helps! However, the only input I have got is a Record variable. I would not be able to query on any of the tables to form a cursor. But I know the table on which this record is based as it is declared using ROWTYPE. So I've got only one record (row) with many fields to print.

Comment: @Iban, missed that part, let me research to see if that is possible and if so how -- sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks in advance! I too tried by using dynamic SQL. I can get the field names by querying dba_tab_columns as I know the table on which the record is based. However, the record is out of scope in dynamic sql block so it's erroring out.

Comment: @iban this may be an out-of-luck situation (I haven't found anything to the contrary), check out this link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3170352229012 ; go to " compare collections column names" then look at Tom's response: 'They are not a runtime introspection sort of thing. They are static. There is no "dynamic access to them". '; if the column names don't change (or don't change often) I would recommend just stripping out the column names and doing as ollie recommended!

Comment: That clears it. So i'll probably put all the column names in  the script. Or I am trying to create another table similar to the record, input the record in the table, and then use your script to print our all the columns in the table. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a PL/SQL block that you are running in an IDE then you could at a pinch use DBMS_OUTPUT to output the values.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm

For example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
   -- Define the record
   TYPE test_rectype IS RECORD (
      field1 NUMBER,
      field2 VARCHAR2
   );
   -- Define a variable for the record
   test_rec TEST_RECTYPE;
BEGIN
   -- Populate the record
   test_rec.field1 := 1;
   test_rec.field2 := 'my value';
   -- Enable the DBMS_OUTPUT
   DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(1000000);
   -- Send the output to the buffer
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Field1: '||test_rec.field1||', Field2: '||test_rec.field2);
END;
```

There is more to DBMS_OUTPUT so take a look at the docs from the link above.

Alternatively, you could write the values to a file using UTL_FILE.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

Hope it helps...

Comment: The record variable which I'm using has more than 50 fields. So is there a better way than using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE for all the 50 fields ?