# Print all column values via only Record using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following plsql script that prints record parameters. 
Is there a way to print all column values just passing `country_record`.
I mean I do not want to write all column name like `country_record.country_id`

```
 DECLARE
       country_record   countries%ROWTYPE;
       countryid        countries.country_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
       countryid := &countryid;

       SELECT *
         INTO country_record
         FROM countries
        WHERE country_id = countryid;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('id: ' || country_record.country_id);
    END;
```

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717251/print-record-fields-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 1):

If printing it all you wanted, you can try out this. Using `SQL*Plus`

```
VARIABLE MYCUR SYSREFCURSOR;

 DECLARE
       country_record   countries%ROWTYPE;
       countryid        countries.country_id%TYPE;
       plsql_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
       countryid := &countryid;

       OPEN :MYCUR for 
       SELECT *
         FROM countries
        WHERE country_id = countryid;

    END;
  /

  print mycur;
```

Comment: I am using TOAD,Is there a similar solution for it?

Comment: Same concept, an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747823/how-to-display-a-sys-refcursor-data-in-toads-datagrid)