# Why bulk collection doesnt works?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I trying to load into some collection all records from table `table_name` using cursor, but it completly doesnt works. When im trying to display some values i have error with uncorrect arguments or uncorrect numbers with that `dbms_output.put_line()`.

Table `table_name` have only intigers in columns and it always have `id` column and x_1...x_10 columns, and have 10 rows. i just don't want to type x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 and etc.

What im doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
  cursor c_Table is
    select * from table_name;
  type x_values is table of game%rowtype;
  x_values_list x_values := x_values();
  square        int := 0;
  id_from_table int := 0;
  temp          int := 0;
BEGIN
  select Max(id) into square from table_name;
  x_values_list.extend(square*square+square);

  /*open table_game;
  fetch table_game bulk collect
    into x_values_list;
    */

  select * bulk collect into x_values_list
  from game;
  for i in 1..square loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x_values_list(i)|| ' ');
  end loop;

END;
```

Comment: you don't Need to extend the collection.  what do you meen it doesn't work?

Comment: `x_values_list(i)` is a record of `game%rowtype` so you can't pass the whole thing to `dbms_output.put_line` which accepts a single string. But this isn't really 'bulk collect not working', though.

Comment: For future reference, an observation that some feature "doesn't work" is not very helpful. You need to describe what actually happens, including any error messages, and explain how this differs from what you wanted to happen.

Comment: Sorry, im noobie with plsql, and i don't know those errors and statements. You need to forgive me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you do have to type `x_1`, `x_2` etc. You are currently trying to pass a record type into `put_line()`, and [that procedure only accepts a string value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html).

The code you've shown will get:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

ebcause you're trying to concatenate a record type with a string; without the `|| ' '` part you'd get:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

There isn't a mechanism to magically convert a record's fields into a single string, you have to do it yourself.

So you will have to do:

```
  for i in 1..x_values_list.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x_values_list(i).id
     || ' ' x_values_list(i).x_1
     || ' ' x_values_list(i).x_2
     || ' ' x_values_list(i).x_3
     -- etc. for all the fields you want to display
    );
  end loop;
```

You could use `dbms_sql` to interrogate the query result metadata ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8717524/266304)) but it's probably not going to be worth the complication.

---

As @hotfix mentioned in a comment, the first two lines of your procedure:

```
  select Max(id) into square from table_name;
  x_values_list.extend(square*square+square);
```

are pointless; the `bulk collect` will completely replace the content of the collection and you don't need to size (extend) it in advance. That's not going to cause you a problem, it's just not needed.

In the loop above I've changed `1..square` to `1..x_values_list.count` so it's based on the actual collection size after the bulk fetch; so you don't need toe `square` local variable at all.

Comment: Have you some other ideas hwo to fix it? To be honest the idea of my "program" is just completly not recomended for plsql but im forcing anyway. I mean i creating `table_name` dynamicaly (by putting numbers of rows and columns as an input value and after that some random values are putted in), so i want to solve that case with taking values from table dynamicaly again (to don't need to type different cases for different sizes of `table_name`). You saying that it's impossible? :)

Comment: @Potato: It's probably not impossible, but I think you'll need to provide a clearer description of what you're trying to do and what part of it you are having trouble with before anyone can answer reliably.

Comment: @Potato - I'm not sure what you mean. It kind of sounds like you're creating a two-dimensional array and populating it with random data, all inside PL/SQL - so is there actually a real schema-level table involved at all?  It will probably be better to ask a new question explaining what you're really doing and what you're actually stuck on.